# Why is Aspnet Identity's PasswordHasher not tied to the User?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

When I hash a password using Aspnet Identity's PasswordHasher, the password is not linked to the `TUser` whose password is set. So technically I can copy that password hash and set it for a different user and that same password hash will work.

The method signature takes `TUser user` as a parameter however it is not used in the hash/salt implementation.

Is this an oversight or is there some other reason `TUser user` is declared in the method signatures but not used?

Line 94:

```
public virtual string HashPassword(TUser user, string password)
```

and
Line 172:

```
public virtual PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
```

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/f555a26b4a554f73eea70b4b34fca823fab9a643/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/PasswordHasher.cs) is source code.

Comment: If you notice, the HashPassword and VerifyPassword are virtual, so they can be overridden.  My guess is that the default hasher does not use any user info, but an overriden one could.

Comment: Oops - I asked (and self-answered) a duplicate over at [What's the user parameter to PasswordHasher's methods used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46793216/whats-the-user-parameter-to-passwordhashers-methods-used-for) without realising that this question existed. I think I've proposed a sensible explanation over there; perhaps close this as a dupe?