# What's the user parameter to PasswordHasher's methods used for?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

In the non-Core version of Identity, [PasswordHasher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher(v=vs.108).aspx) is a non-generic type. Its `HashPassword` method takes a single argument (the password to hash), and its `VerifyHashedPassword` method takes only two (the password hash generated previously by `HashPassword`, and the provided password to verify. This is great, because it means that I can use `PasswordHasher` without going all-in and using the whole Identity framework.

In `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, on the other hand, [`PasswordHasher<TUser>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1?view=aspnetcore-2.0) is now a generic class, and the `HashPassword` and `VerifyHashedPassword` methods take a `user` parameter in addition to the parameters that existed previously. This doesn't make much sense to me. Why does either hashing a password or verifying a hash require the user object? What's it used for?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nothing. We can see in the source at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs that neither the type parameter `TUser` nor any of the `user` parameters to the class's methods are ever used, at all.

I'd guess that the idea of having these parameters on the [`IPasswordHasher<TUser>`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IPasswordHasher.cs) interface is to permit application-specific subclasses that *do* depend upon the user. For instance, I can imagine a situation where after a merger of two applications with different userbases, an application ends up having to deal with users whose passwords were hashed using different algorithms. Storing something like a `PasswordFormat` field on the user model would then allow a custom `IPasswordHasher<TUser>` to select which hashing algorithm to use based upon the user.

Comment: If you're using the default `PasswordHasher` implementation, what would be a reasonable thing to pass in as `TUser`?  A `true` bool?